How to get centers of circles arranged in a grid in specific order in opencv
I have some approximate circles in an approximate grid shape, but there is distortion.
How can I get the centers in the order of left to right, top to bottom?
I tried findCirclesGrid, but I don't think it works with distortion.
I don't think blob detection has an order.


I've been meaning to work on some code that robustly recovers the grid structure from a set of points... but that takes time and motivation

This question is similar to: Python: Sorting items from top left to bottom right with OpenCV. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should check the excellent answer I suggested as a duplicate

superficially similar, but not really. the answer you linked forces the points into a user-supplied number of rows, no matter what grid shape underlies the points. if the grid were rotated any more, it would definitely just cut across the rows and mangle the structure. the linked answer is quite trivial (get_rows), once stripped of the secondary code (extracting the objects to get points).

the other answer on the linked question actually shows some deeper understanding. it suggests clustering sensitive to the data, rather than requiring a user-supplied number of clusters. "clustering" describes the result. it's not a specific approach. here, "clustering" would be nontrivial because the grid is warped nonlinearly: points don't lie in any straight line. and precisely that is the challenge I alluded to in my first comment. I have approaches in mind and have toyed with the problem in the past. robust solutions are far from trivial.

@VanushVee you might want to add a second image to the question that shows a grid that's warped more strongly... if your application has those instances. we don't need to make the problem harder than it is, but there is use in seeing how difficult the problem can be.

findCirclesGrid, being needed in camera calibration, should be able to recover warped grids. IDK if it can handle this pattern though. some search results suggest that it should. CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID | CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING helped someone at some point. your picture might be more challenging because the circles are "lumpy".

a bit of investigation: the blob detector needs to get all its filtering disabled. then i'll find the blobs: https://i.sstatic.net/itvRGS0j.png and findCirclesGrid can find the structure: https://i.sstatic.net/Ddr0WXA4.png (this required lack of clustering flag; clustering impl makes it misassign points). all of that requires you to know the size of the grid and all the points to be visible. any missing ones will ruin this.

findCirclesGrid() is intended for camera calibration. Such patterns are expected to have distortion, just like yours. It's definitely supposed to work on your data.
It just needs a little help. It uses a BlobDetector internally, which is initialized with some defaults that work well for the usual circles grids that show well-defined circles.
For your picture, you need a BlobDetector with custom parameters. To find all those lumpy blobs, you need to disable all the filtering it usually does.
params = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.filterByArea = False
params.filterByCircularity = False
params.filterByColor = False
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.filterByInertia = False

blobdet = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

Result of keypoints = blobdet.detect(im) and cv.drawKeypoints():

You also need to be careful with the flags to findCirclesGrid(). CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING failed in that it misassigned points to grid positions.
(rv, gridpts) = cv.findCirclesGrid(
    im, (10, 7),
    flags=cv.CALIB_CB_SYMMETRIC_GRID,
    blobDetector=blobdet)

And that'll give you gridpts having shape (70, 1, 2).
Some visualization:
im_with_grid = cv.cvtColor(cv.pyrUp(im >> 1), cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

for k in range(1, len(gridpts)):
    [p1] = gridpts[k-1]
    [p2] = gridpts[k]
    cv.line(im_with_grid, (p1 * 2.0).astype(int), (p2 * 2.0).astype(int), (0, 0, 255), 2)

for i,[pt] in enumerate(gridpts):
    cv.circle(im_with_grid, (pt * 2.0).astype(int), 5, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    cv.putText(
        im_with_grid, f"{i}", (pt * 2.0).astype(int),
        cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv.LINE_AA )


Or if you specify the grid size as (7, 10), it'll be flipped along its diagonal and look like this:

Caveat
findCirclesGrid will fail if the grid has any defects, i.e. missing points. It can't go around those defects. You need a perfect detection of all grid points.
